# tableviewのセルを選択したとき画面遷移をし、遷移先の画面にその詳細情報を表示する

Tags: swift, xcode

タイトルのような機能を実現する為に調べたのですが、

tableviewで一覧画面を作るところまではできて、理解もできたのですが、
セルを選択したときに画面遷移をして遷移先の画面でそのセルの詳細情報を表示する方法が理解できませんでした。

UItableviewcontrollerのサブクラスとして新たにクラスを作った時に最初から書いてある、prepare()メソッドと、
didselectrow()メソッドを使うというところまでは理解できました。
ただその中に具体的に何を書いていけばいいか、などがわかりません。

できるだけ細かく教えていただきたいです。

抽象的な質問ですがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「UITableViewに一覧を表示して、それをタップすると画面遷移して詳細が表示される」という形態はiOSアプリのもっとも典型的なパターンの1つです。

なので、Xcodeのプロジェクトテンプレートとして、その雛形がすでに用意されています。

新規プロジェクトを作成し、**Master-Detail App**のテンプレートを選んでみてください。
これだけで、「UITableViewに一覧を表示して、それをタップすると画面遷移して詳細が表示される」アプリが出来上がります。

このプロジェクトの MasterViewController, DetailViewController, Main.storyboard にあなたが求めている方法の答えがあるはずです。

（抽象的な質問にできるだけ細かい回答をしようとするのは骨が折れるのでそれ以外の回答で）

Comment: ありがとうございます！お教えいただいた方法で作ってみたいと思います。